# python script for value extraction, split data and reformat

Tags: python

This question is largely related to logic and somewhat to syntax.

I'm creating a short python script to extract just some few "tidbits" of information from many hundreds of records. So far I'm pretty close but the code requires a modification which I'm seemingly incapable of formulating.

I have data of the following form:

```
368 1   "Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 2
Use or provision of open data (1): 2
Use or provision of open data (2): 2
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 2
Market opportunity and timing (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (1): 2
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 1
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 1
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 1"
368 2   "Overall evaluation: 2
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 2
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 3
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 2
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
```

I need to grab those values but also to associate them with the number that comes in front so, for instance, for the first one, I need it to be something like:

```
368

=2+3+3+3+4+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+4+3+2+3+2

=2+3+3+3+4+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+4+3+2+3+2
```

and so on, for many more instances.

So I need to tweeze out the instance identifier, in this case `368` and also the values associated with that record for the two reviews.

I know how to extract the values for the reviews, namely, like this:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        number = int(line.split(':')[1])
        array.append(number)
print '+'.join(array)
```

but I can't figure out how to render it with the record identifier as I tried to demonstrate above with the example

---

*EDIT*

The data looks like this:

```
299 1   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 2
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
299 2   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 3
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 2"

364 1   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 3
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 4
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (3): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
364 2   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 4
""Open by default"" (1): 4
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 3
Market opportunity and timing (1): 2
Market opportunity and timing (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would've done. This does your job, not perfectly but does it.

Also, `1.txt` is the same text as yours.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
head='0'
body=[]
for x in f:
    if x=="\n" or x.strip()=='':
        continue
    try:
        int(x[0])
        print(head +':'+'+'.join(body))
        tmp=x.split()
        head=tmp[0]+'-'+tmp[1]
        body=[tmp[4]]
    except ValueError as e:
        body.append(x.split(':')[1].strip().strip('\"'))
print(head +':'+'+'.join(body))
```

Output would be:

```
0:
299-1:3+3+4+3+3+4+3+2+3+4+2+4+4+4+2+2+3+4+4+3+4+3
299-2:3+3+3+2+4+4+3+3+2+4+3+4+3+3+2+1+4+4+4+4+4+2
364-1:3+3+4+1+3+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+4+4+3+3+3+4+3+3+3
364-2:3+3+4+3+3+4+4+4+3+4+3+2+3+4+4+1+3+3+2+4+4+2
```

Now you can skip the first print by adding a check for length of the array, so you don't print the `0:` line.

Comment: seems something is amiss, the code output this `0:
299-1:3+3+4+3+3+4+3+2+3+4+2+4+4+4+2+2+3+4+4+3+4+3
` and then a  "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I'm assuming that the heading like 382 is followed by a statement in the same string which ends with a number. The sample you provided, works fine. Maybe the data you have is a bit different. But the thing to take away from this is that check if the line starts from a number by a try statement.

Comment: I just put a more comprehensive sample of the data- maybe it has to do with the fact that in the more complete set there are blank lines?

Comment: There you go. Made the changes to accommodate new lines and spaces.

Comment: It would, but what if the line has whitespaces? Data can be dirty at times.

Comment: yeah- those blank lines are definetly the problem. could I do something like if line is a blank line continue or soemthing?

Comment: I did change the code. This will continue when a blank line or whitespaces occur. Check the new edit.

Comment: you are a hacking god